# How to manipulate fields and references that are read from database with Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have in my application a model that looks something like this:

```js
const EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  address: {
    street: String,
    zipCode: String,
    city: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'City',
      autopopulate: { select: 'cityName state' }
    }
  },
  ...
  // and a bunch of other fields
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Employee', EmployeeSchema, 'employees');
```

This is the main model I'm working with. However, if the client wants to draw the full list of all employees from the database, the server should return a big array with all employees. In order to make the data smaller, I have another model that shows only snippet of the needed information, which would look like this:

```js
const EmployeeSnippetSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  residenceCity: String,
  residenceState: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('EmployeeSnippet', EmployeeSnippetSchema, 'employees');
```

Now, if the client wants an array with the full list of all employees in the database, I simply make this call:

```js
EmployeeSnippet.find()...
```

In the main schema, the 'city' field of 'address' is just a reference to a different collection ('cities) in the database. How can I make the call with EmployeeSnippet that will draw the 'cityName' and 'state' values from the 'cities' collection and populate them in the 'residenceCity' and 'residenceState' respectively? (Considering that it is during an operation in which the server draws hundreds (potentially thousands) of records from the db.)

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found a solution that works, although I don't know if it's optimal for cases when I draw a large number of documents of a model from the db. But, in any case here it is.

I need to use the post hook for init on the schema of the snippet. In other words, the EmployeeSnippet should look like this:

```js
const EmployeeSnippetSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  address: {
    city: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'City',
      autopopulate: { select: 'cityName state' }
    }
  },
  residenceCity: String,
  residenceState: String
});
```

The I just add the following hook:

```js
EmployeeSnippetSchema.post('init', function(doc) {
  if (doc.address && doc.address.city) {
    doc.residenceCity = doc.address.city.cityName;
    doc.residenceState = doc.address.state;
  }
  
  delete doc.address;
});
```

And that works, although as I said earlier, I don't know if that's an optimized solution when we get a large number of documents, but that's the best I could come up with.

P.S. I just realized that I used 'autopopulate' which is not a feature that comes out-of-the-box with mongoose. This is actually a plugin by the Mongoose team: http://plugins.mongoosejs.io/plugins/autopopulate

Answer (score 0):

I actually found another way, which I assume is more optimized because it delegates all of this work to the actual database engine. This is using aggregate. With it, I actually don't even need to create a whole new model for the snippet—I could just get it from the main model. This is how I made it:

```js
Employee.aggregate()
  .lookup({
    from: 'cities',
    localField: 'residenceAddress.city',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'residenceAddress'
  })
  .addFields({
    residenceCity: { $arrayElemAt: ['$residenceAddress', 0] },
    residenceState: { $arrayElemAt: ['$residenceAddress', 0] }
  })
  .project({
    firstName: 1,
    lastName: 1,
    residenceCity: '$residenceCity.cityName',
    residenceState: '$residenceState.state',
  })
  .then((result) => {
    // do whatever stuff I need with the snippet resulting from this process
  });
```